# Custom active navigation on primary menu

Tags: wordpress

I am using Twenty Sixteen theme and Create a new post type.

```
function twentysixteen_setup() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => __( 'News'),
    'singular_name'      => __( 'News'),
    'menu_name'          => __( 'News'),
    'add_new'            => __('Add News')
);


$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'description'        => __( 'Description.'),
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'  => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'news' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt')
);

register_post_type( 'news', $args );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentysixteen_setup' );
```

I have also create Page with name News.On click on News page it shows news list. But it is not showing Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function in function.php file and upload on server. It's working fine for me.

```
function sid_custom_menu_classes($menu)
{
    global $post;
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'news')
     {
         $menu = str_replace( 'current-menu-item', '', $menu ); // remove all current_page_parent classes
         $menu = str_replace( 'menu-item-77', 'menu-item-77 current-menu-item', $menu ); // add the current_page_parent class to the page you want
      }
   return $menu;
 }
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'sid_custom_menu_classes', 10,2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

update your permalink in settings and try. It will work fine.

**Note:**

Just update. no need to change any permalink post type.  It will work fine.

```
        add_action( 'init', 'codex_book_init' );
        /**
         * Register a book post type.
         *
         * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type
         */
        function codex_book_init() {
            $labels = array(
                'name'               => _x( 'news', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
                'singular_name'      => _x( 'news', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
                'menu_name'          => _x( 'news', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
                'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'news', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
                'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'news', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),

            );

            $args = array(
                'labels'             => $labels,
                        'description'        => __( 'Description.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
                'public'             => true,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'show_ui'            => true,
                'show_in_menu'       => true,
                'query_var'          => true,
                'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'news' ),
                'capability_type'    => 'post',
                'has_archive'        => true,
                'hierarchical'       => false,
                'menu_position'      => null,
                'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
            );

            register_post_type( 'news', $args );
        }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: login your admin panel. go to the settings in menu and permalink

Comment: and then click on save changes button

Comment: I have multiple option which options I will choose

Comment: Plain  http://localhost/wp-test/?p=123
Day and name  http://localhost/wp-test/2016/12/16/sample-post/
Month and name  http://localhost/wp-test/2016/12/sample-post/
Numeric  http://localhost/wp-test/archives/123
Post name  http://localhost/wp-test/sample-post/
Custom Structure http://localhost/wp-test/

Comment: select this option--> Post name

Comment: I have already selected , It works fine on other pages but not shows on News page

Comment: Can you share email id so that I can share my code. To check

Comment: I have post solution and its working fine. Thanks for your help